# Redirecting on session timeout in JSF-Richfaces-facelet

Tags: jsf, richfaces, facelets

I am using JSF with RichFacecs to create a web portal .I want to redirect the user to the login page on session time out. I was trying to throw a SecurityException in session expiry/logged out stage as follows

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.SecurityException</exception-type>
    <location>/Login.jsf</location>
</error-page>
```

But this is not working for me. Which is the right way of handling this ?

Answer (score 7):

This should do it :

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/sessionExpired.jsf</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this and its not working for ajax request

Comment: Can you show how you have implemented the session expired page? Its important that the redirect function that your using is also not timed out  =)

Comment: i am redirecting the login page on session expire. I got another working solution. Now i am redirecting in the backing bean like this 
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("login.jsf") . Is this a proper way ?

Comment: I dont see any problems with this approach. Im glad you found a working approach.

Answer (score 4):

you should put a timeout in your web.xml and register a timeout filter as shown in this thread: [Auto-logout in JSF Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503303/auto-logout-in-jsf-application)
in case of ajax, your redirection has to be done like that:

```
    String facesRequestHeader = httpServletRequest
            .getHeader( "Faces-Request" );

    boolean isAjaxRequest = facesRequestHeader != null
            && facesRequestHeader.equals( "partial/ajax" );

    if( isAjaxRequest )
    {
            String url = MessageFormat.format( "{0}://{1}:{2,number,####0}{3}",
            request.getScheme(), request.getServerName(),
            request.getServerPort(), timeoutPath );

            PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
                pw.println( "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" );
            pw.println( "<partial-response><redirect url=\"" + url
            + "\"></redirect></partial-response>" );
            pw.flush(););
    }
    else
    {
        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect( timeoutPath );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use Richfaces own `session expired event`.

Add this to the page prone to expire:

```
<a4j:region>
 <script language="javascript">
 A4J.AJAX.onExpired = function(loc, expiredMsg){
 alert('expired!');
 window.location = "/login.jsf";
 }
 </script>
</a4j:region>
```

More info can be found at the RichFaces documentation:
http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html#SessionExpiredHandling

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems when I  making A4J requests after session expiration.
I put this

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

in my web.xml, for me it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create CustomViewHandler that extends ViewHandler 
and override restoreView method

```
@Override
public UIViewRoot restoreView(FacesContext facesContext, String viewId) {
/**
 * {@link javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException}. This happens only  when we try to logout from timed out pages.
 */
    UIViewRoot root = null; 
    root = parent.restoreView(facesContext, viewId);
    if(root == null) {          
        root = createView(facesContext, viewId);
    }
    return root;
}
```

Then you need to add it to your faces-config.xml

```
<view-handler>com.demo.CustomViewHandler</view-handler>
```

This will prevent you from getting ViewExpiredException's

Comment: Note: I think "parent" should be "super" and can be added to createView also. I would also suggest that an implementation of ViewHandler like com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl be extended so that you don't need to rewrite all of the ViewHandler classes.