# After session timeout where does JBoss redirect users to?

Tags: jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee, jboss

After this is reached in JBoss:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

where does it redirect users to? Can I change the page it redirects to?

Comment: It's depends upon you and your code.

Comment: Stella, please read the answers given on your others question !
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503303/auto-logout-in-jsf-application

Comment: Stella, I notice that you never accepted any answer to your questions ..

Answer (score 1):

Stella,

As explained in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503303/auto-logout-in-jsf-application), this can be defined by using a JSF Filter...