# Session timedout in jsf

Tags: java, session, jsf-2, session-timeout, ajax4jsf

I have an issue, my whole JSF application is based on Ajax Requests

We do every request and everything using Ajax

The problem is when the session is timed out and the user tries to do anything on the page it just do nothing.

I know that the session is timed out but I wasn't able to catch it. after some trying finally I'm able to catch when the session is timed out after each request. but the problem now is to redirect the user to the login screen again from the filter or the managed bean or even using js

Please anyone can tell me what to do to redirect the user to the login screen

also please keep in mind that I have three pages in my application : login and index and logout only and everything is in the index page

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like that in order to make an ajax redirection inside your timeout filter. You can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438351/redirecting-on-session-timeout-in-jsf-richfaces-facelet/10431023#10431023)

```
String facesRequestHeader = httpServletRequest
        .getHeader( "Faces-Request" );

boolean isAjaxRequest = facesRequestHeader != null
        && facesRequestHeader.equals( "partial/ajax" );

if( isAjaxRequest )
{
        String url = MessageFormat.format( "{0}://{1}:{2,number,####0}{3}",
        request.getScheme(), request.getServerName(),
        request.getServerPort(), timeoutPath );

        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
            pw.println( "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" );
        pw.println( "<partial-response><redirect url=\"" + url
        + "\"></redirect></partial-response>" );
        pw.flush(););
}
else
{
    httpServletResponse.sendRedirect( timeoutPath );
}
```

Comment: It's not working

still the page do nothing when the session is timeout

Comment: It does a redirection when the user execute any action in the page?

Comment: please put a breakpoint and check that your filter is working. And be sure the URL exists.

Comment: It enter the filter then everything goes okay but I get an exception says that you can commit the response twice at the line chain.doFilter(req,res)
when I remove it nothing happens when I go to the login screen when launching the app
and says this This webpage has a redirect loop

Comment: This piece of code just builds the response in case of an ajax or non-ajax request, therefore you don't need to chain any other filter. I would just put a return to the doFilter function after this piece of code.

Comment: If after login you were send to this pice of code is because your timeout filter is not well configured as there is no timeout after login, please check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503303/auto-logout-in-jsf-application