# validation before rendering page

Tags: jsf-2

I'm new to JSF and using JSF2 to build a webapp which has several pages. I'm using a session scoped bean to keep some parameters that were set by going through the different pages.

When the session times out (or I redeploy the app) and I go to a specific page then this page is not able to render correctly because some data is missing from the session. At this point I want the home page to be shown.

I want to use this mechanism for all pages. So in general I want to do some validation before rendering a page and direct the user to the home page if the validation fails.

How should I handle this?

Comment: Similar question (and answers) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1438351/620338)

Comment: In my use case, with a session timeout, I mean that the data in my session bean is not available anymore. This is what I want to respond to by directing the user to a different page. I do also have a problem when I get a ViewExpiredException but this is a different issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case I'd use a simple [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which hooks on JSF requests and checks the presence of the managed bean in the session. The below example assumes the following:

- `FacesServlet` is definied in `web.xml` as `<servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>`
- Your session scoped bean has a managed bean name of `yourSessionBean`.
- Your home page is located at `home.xhtml`

---

```
@WebFilter(servletName="facesServlet")
public class FacesSessionFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

        if (!request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/home.xhtml") && (session == null || session.getAttribute("yourSessionBean") == null)) {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/home.xhtml"); // Redirect to home page.
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res); // Bean is present in session, so just continue request.
        }
    }

    // Add/generate init() and destroy() with empty bodies.
}
```

Or if you want to do it more JSF-ish, add a `<f:event type="preRenderView">` to the master template.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{someBean.preRenderView}" />
</f:metadata>
```

with

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{yourSessionBean}")
private YourSessionBean yourSessionBean;

public void preRenderView() {
    if (yourSessionBean.isEmpty()) {
        yourSessionBean.addPage("home");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/home.xhtml");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx BalusC. I indeed would prefer the JSF-ish solution. I tried it but when the session bean is empty then it goes into a never ending loop. So I probably need to redirect only when I'm not on the home page (like your first solution). I'll try this the way you described.

Comment: Makes sense. You'd like to change the session bean in some way so that the condition evaluates false after the redirect. I edited the answer. You could also do this job in the `@PostConctruct` of a managed bean associated with `home.xhtml`.

Comment: Do you mean here that the yourSessionBean.addPage("home") is making the yourSessionBean.isEmpty() return false?