# NullpointerException in getExternalContext in FacesContext

Tags: java, jsf

I tried to get external context from FacesContext as followed and got NullPointerException:

```
ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
```

What could possibly cause the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It can only be caused if [`FacesContext#getCurrentInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getCurrentInstance%28%29) returned `null`. Any attempt to access or invoke a `null` reference will result in `NullPointerException`. See also [its javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html):

> Thrown when an application attempts to use `null` in a case where an object is required. These include:
>
> - Calling the instance method of a `null` object.
> - Accessing or modifying the field of a `null` object.
> - Taking the length of `null` as if it were an array.
> - Accessing or modifying the slots of `null` as if it were an array.
> - Throwing `null` as if it were a `Throwable` value.
>
> Applications should throw instances of this class to indicate other illegal uses of the `null` object.

That `FacesContext#getCurrentInstance()` returns `null` can in turn only be caused if that line of code is **not** been executed inside the JSF context, i.e. when the code is **not** running during a HTTP request which is been served by the `FacesServlet`, who's the one responsible for creating the `FacesContext` as `ThreadLocal`. For example, inside a plain servlet, servlet filter or servlet listener or any other code which isn't executed during a HTTP request which runs the `FacesServlet`.

How to solve it properly depends on the functional requirement which isn't clear from the question. Generally, you'd either make sure that the HTTP request runs through the `FacesServlet`, or to access the information you're looking for by alternate means which is more appropriate for the context the code is currently running in.

Comment: Thanks very much for your highly detail account:). Since thats all the lines of code I implemented(Related to jsf), I suppose that I need to get HTTP request up running. Would you be able to suggest me the simplest way to do it?

Comment: As said, that really depends on the context where this line of code is running and the functional requirement. Where exactly is that line of code running? What exactly would you like to do for which you thought that the `ExternalContext` would be suitable? The `ExternalContext` is merely a facade around `ServletContext`, `HttpServletRequest`, `HttpSession` and `HttpServletResponse`. If either of them is available in the context where your code is running, just use one of them directly. Feel free to ask a new question wherein you describe the functional requirement in detail.

Comment: Basically, I need to be able to transfer a user to from my screen to another tool in a different screen using ExternalContext#redirect.

Comment: Again, what's the context where the code is currently running in? Is it for example inside `doFilter()` method of a servlet filter? If so, cast the provided `ServletResponse` argument to `HttpServletResponse` and use its `sendRedirect()` method. If you really insist doing it the JSF-ish way check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384327/validation-before-rendering-page/6386785#6386785) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294651/is-there-any-easy-way-to-preprocess-and-redirect-get-requests/7294707#7294707) answer