# How to redirect in javax.servlet.Filter's doFilter

Tags: java, spring, jsf, redirect, servlet-filters

I making my first school project using Spring and JSF and I'm supposed to override `javax.servlet.Filter`'s `doFilter` method for access control and redirecting when a user does not have permissions to access a certain url. I'm using NetBeans.

**WEB-INF/web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

...
<filter>
    <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filters.AuthFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/views/filtered/auth/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
...
```

**AuthFilter.java**

```
package filters;

/**
* This class checks if an authenticated user is trying to access its url, else redirect
*/
public class AuthFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();
        Authenticated authenticated = (Authenticated) session.getAttribute("authenticated");

        if (authenticated == null) {
            //option 1, use ExternalContext
            ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
            try {
                externalContext.redirect(
                        externalContext.getRequestContextPath()
                        + externalContext.getRequestServletPath()
                        + "/views/filtered/nonauth/login.xhtml");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //option 2
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            httpResponse.sendRedirect("../filtered/nonauth/login.xhtml");

        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

If I try Option 1, it throws a null pointer exception on `FacesContext` ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8300469/4770813) by BalusC explains why)

OTOH, Option 2 seems to be location dependent, meaning it works from some urls and from others goes into an infinite redirect loop.

My question is, what's the proper way to redirect the user to the `login.xhtml` page, independently of the "place" he made the unauthorized request from?

Thanks

Comment: Just don't use jsf refirects, use plain servlet related code. Get the servlet context from the servlet request

Comment: @Kukeltje, indeed the answer you pointed out helped me solve my problem. I feel like it´d be in the best interest of the community if I deleted this question. what do you think? thanks

Comment: Not needed. Sometimes questions asked in a different way help others out.