# Problem to inject СDI Bean in @WebServlet in JSF 4.0

Tags: jsf, servlets, cdi, facescontext

Excuse me, I'm recently learning programming and Java,  mostly from YouTube videos. The problem is that all these videos are based on outdated frameworks, while I am trying to do the same thing using modern versions of the software.

I recently encountered a problem,  I could not get a CDI Bean (@SessionScoped) in a servlet (regular @WebServlet) as a session attribute (in turn obtained from an HTTP request), although this is exactly what was shown in the video (True, it was not a CDI Bean, but a @ManagedBean (eager = true) that was used there - depricated). The bean was null all the time. For about a week I tried to find something about this on the Internet, I thought that the problem was just in the “eager” property (CDI has “lazy”, and it seems that it cannot be changed), but the only thing I found out is that, access to the Face Context is “not guaranteed” from files and classes that are not related to JSF tools, such as WebServlets. I still solved this situation in my own way - right in the CDI constructor I put Bean in the session (using ExternalContext.getSession), and in the servlet processing the request I took Bean out of the session:

```
@Named(value = "searchController")
@SessionScoped
public class SearchController implements Serializable {

private Class class;
private static Map<String, SearchType> searchList = new HashMap<String, 
SearchType>(); 

 ...

public SearchController() {
    ........

    **((HttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                    .getExternalContext().getSession(false))
                    .setAttribute("searchController", this);**    
}
```

and in WebServlet:

```
SearchController searchController = (SearchController) 
     request.getSession(false).getAttribute("searchController");
```

But this is not the ending.

I've published this variant under one of similar topic here, and received an advice  just to inject the CDI Bean in @WebServlet, through annotation @Inject. Without any details. So I,ve tried to do it, added in @WebServlet @Inject SerchController searchController, removed definition of this attribute from the constructor, but it doesn't work, in WebServlet FaceContext is null. WebServlet is not a Face component. Fs I understood when I was learning Spring (in this project i don't use Spring), we always injected beans in Spring components, but how to resolve this problem here? What I'm doing wrong?

My advisors on the previous thread gave me a link to a post 13 years ago [NullpointerException in getExternalContext in FacesContext](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8300439), but even there I read the same thing I already read: @Inject does not work (or work is not guaranteed) if CDI beans are injected into elements that are not JSF components. My comment was hidden, I agree, it was far from the question, but I would like these knowledgeable guys to come here and show me their solution, especially since it is much simpler than mine. I would be very grateful.

I wanted to receive a signuture - how to inject CDI Bean in @WebServlet

Comment: So you can not inject CDI BeaN  in WebServlet?  But your first comment on the previos thread was "This all is unnecessary. You can just @Inject the CDI bean into the servlet :) " . Is it the same you are writting here?!

Comment: Sorry, I don't uderstand.  You said it in your first comment. One more time:  I need to use WebServlet as in the video. When I put  CDI Bean in the HTTP Session in CDI's constructoe, everything work. When I try to inject CDI in WebServlet without chahging constructor- it doesn't work.   In the second way Bean is ilways null. So?

Comment: By the way. in the video there is no injections at all. There they simply  address to Bean by name from the WebServlet as to session's attribute

Comment: Thak you, because I didn't know it))))  It is the same what I said at the beginning)))) Do you read my posts carefully? I don't think so. The matter ist I did. it(((!!!!). In my way. With adding bean in HttpSession as attribute in CDI Bean's constructor and extracting it in @WebServlet  Adding only two lines of code. It works!!! That was because I posted that answer - I thought, it might be usefull for somebody and at the time I hoped - if I had done a mistake, somebody would correct me. I understand that the thing was far from topic, I agree that my answer was hidden, I opend my own thread.

Comment: May be it is a crutch, may be I don't know something, but you didn't show me it, you are only repeating that I can not. First  you offered me to inject me CDI in Servlet, then said that it is imposible, then refused from your first words, then - to remove all JSF, alsough it was my task to learn JSF))) Is it OK?!

Comment: That was clear from context. I pointed clearly, that I'm using @WebServlet, and first you adviced me to inject there CDI Bean (withoun any remarks about FaceServlet).  I'm not going to post our messages here step by step, it's stupid.  I know and you know - what  we wrote each other, or can refresh it if it is necessary. Read the body of my question carefully, and, I hope, you'll find that I had already known that I cannot access FacesContext outside the context of the FacesServlet (directly).