# How to redirect login page in Jsf + Spring security project's when session timeout.?

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security, richfaces

below code fragment i added in my **web xml** file

```
 <session-config>
  <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
 </session-config>
```

i need to know is there any possibility to redirect to my login page when application session time out.?

I used JSF 2 + Spring security 3 + Richfaces final in my project
please advice me 
thanks all

Comment: all server requests barred after timeout. need to add actions after all button events.?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438351/redirecting-on-session-timeout-in-jsf-richfaces-facelet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to that automatically or you want to redirect to login page after session timeout when user call some action. 
for second one I can recommend this method. I've tested this method in my project and it will work for sure. 
https://gist.github.com/banterCZ/5160269

but if you want to that with Richfaces use this:
[Redirecting on session timeout in JSF-Richfaces-facelet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438351/redirecting-on-session-timeout-in-jsf-richfaces-facelet)