# Redirecting back to current page when session timeout

Tags: spring, session, jsf, seam

I need to configure a method under a web application using Spring, JSF and Seam that when a session timeout and a user login again, it redirect to the page that it was before.

I configure in web.xml the session timeout:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

In faces-config.xml always redirect to home.xhtml:

```
<navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>/general/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{identity.login}</from-action>
          <if>#{identity.loggedIn}</if>
            <to-view-id>/general/home.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
    </navigation-case>          

    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{identity.login}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>failed</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/general/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>      
</navigation-rule>
```

Any ideas?

Its not the same case as redirect to the login page on sesion expire. This part I got it cover. I want that after login redirect to the same page that I was before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting on session timeout in JSF-Richfaces-facelet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438351/redirecting-on-session-timeout-in-jsf-richfaces-facelet)

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra Its not a duplicate because i this case I want to redirect to the previous page before the session expire.